# Alternative approach to database design: "verticality"

Tags: database, entity-attribute-value

I would like to ask someone, who has experiences in database design. This is my idea, and I can't assess deep consequences of such approach to, let's say, common problem. I appreciate your comments in advance...

Imagine: 
- patients in hospital
- each patient should have:
   1. personal data - Name, Surname, Street, SecurityID, contact, and many more (which could be changed over time)
   2. personal records - a heap of various forms (also changing over time)

Typically I would design table for patient's pesonal data:

personaldata_tbl
  | ID | SecurityID | Name | Surname ... | TimeOfEntry

and similar tables for each form in program. This could be very hard task, because it could reach several hundreds of such tables. In addition to it, probably their count will be increasingly growing.
And yes, all of them should be relationally connected for example:

releaseform_tbl
  | ID | personaldata_tbl_ID | DateOfRelease | CauseOfRelease ... | TimeOfEntry

My intention is to revert 2D tables to single 1D table - all data about patients would be stored in one table! Other tables will describe (referentially) what kind of data is stored in the main table. Look at this:

data_info_tbl
| ID | Description | 
|  1 | Name | 
|  2 | Surname |

patient_data_tbl
| ID | patient_ID | data_info_ID | form_ID | TimeOfEntry | Value
|  1 | 121 | 1 | 7 | 17.12.2011 14:34 | John
|  2 | 121 | 2 | 7 | 17.12.2011 14:34 | Smith

The main reason, why this approach attracts me is:
- simplicity
- ability to store any data with appropriate specification and precision
- no table jungle

Contras:
- SQL querying could be problematic in some cases
- there should be reliable algorithm to delete, update, insert data (one way is to dynamically create table, perform operations on it, and finally store it)
- dataaware controls won't be used.

So what would you say ?

thanx for your time and answers

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problems . . .

**You lose control of size**. The "Value" column must be big enough to hold the largest type you use, which in the general case must be a blob. (X-ray images, in a hospital database.)

**You lose data types**. PostgreSQL, for example, includes the data types "point", bit string, internet address, cidr address, MAC address, and UUID. Storing all values in a column of a single type means you lose all the type-safety built into the specific data types.

**You lose constraints**. Some integers need to be constrained to between 1 and 10, others between 1000 and 3000. Some text strings need to be all numbers (ZIP codes), some need to be a particular mix of alpha and numerics (tire sizes).

**You lose scalability**. If there are 1000 attributes in a person's medical records, each person's data will take 1000 rows in the table. If you have 100,000 patients--an easily manageable number even in Microsoft Access and SQLite--your table suddenly balloons from a manageable 100,000 rows to 100,000,000 rows. Any query that does a table scan will have to scan 100 million rows, every time.  Any single query that needs to return, say, 30 attributes will need 30 joins.

What you're proposing is the [EAV anti-pattern](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2670985/SQL-Antipatterns). (Starts on slide 30.)

Comment: Excelent. Some "solutions":
ad 1. and 2. : I may use more columns: value_int, value_char, value_blob
ad 3. it can be managed through application
ad 4. that was the question, I don't not know the answer and I am worry about. One solution is to use big mother table and small current table (with only hospitalized patients)

Comment: @lyborko: You're right--you *don't* know the answer, and you *should* be worried. I've been doing this stuff for 25 years, and I can guarantee you that if you built a hospital system this way, you'd hate your life in less than a week, and you'd probably be fired, too. But don't take our word for it. Build a prototype, put test data for 10,000 patients into it, and try to do some reports.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Bert Evans (in the sense that I don't find this terribly valid).

First of all it's not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve. The three "benefits" you list:

- simplicity
- ability to store any data with appropriate specification
  and precision
- no table jungle

don't really make a lot of sense if the application is small, and if it isn't (like hospital records you mention in your example) any possible "gain" is lost when you start to factor in that this will make any sort of query very inefficient, and that human operators trying to design reports, data extractions or to extend the DB will have to put in a lot of extra effort.

Example: I suppose your hospital patient has an address and therefore a ZIP code... have you considered what loops you will have to jump in to create foreing index on the zip code/state table?

Another example: as soon as you realize that the patient may have a middle name and that on the form it will be placed between the first and last name what will you do? renumber all the last name fields? or place the middle name at the bottom of the pile, so that your form will have to re-add special logic to show it in the "correct" position?

You may want to check some alternatives to SQL DBs, like for example XML based data stores, or even MUMPS, but I really can't see any benefit in the approach you are proposing (and please consider I had seen an over-zealous DBA trying to do something very similar when designing a web application backed by an Oracle DB: every field/label/image on the webpage had just a numeric reference to a sequence-based ID record in the DB, making the whole webapp a nightmare to mantain - so I am not just being a "purist" here).

Comment: 1. extra effort by data extraction - correct. Especially WHERE AND OR operations could be difficult to perform.

Comment: I do not see any difficulty about zip code, neither "middle name" problem. I am not sure, if you understand me completely. Middle name will get next data_info id, it does not matter if you place it on the form next to the last name or somewhere else.

Comment: Please describe how your system guarantees foreign key consistency between the zip in the patient table and the zip in the region/country/state/whatever table. I.e. how you guarantee that the zip you enter exists already in a master data table.

Comment: regarding the middle name problem: I supposed that the only "benefit" you could arguably present for your idea was that this way forms would be auto-generated by the table structure itself. Apparently this is not the case, so I suppose that forms now will require even more meta-data and I guess you will have a "Form" table with records describing how to use the "patients" records to build the form for adding, deleting etc.